# TS2339: Property 'text' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular11

I am actually facing this line problem :- `<input [(ngModel)]="question.text" name="question" matInput placeholder="Question">`here .text extension make problem. Here I used Angular11.  here is my code.

Question.component.html

```
<mat-card >

<mat-card-content>

<form>
   
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Question</mat-label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="question.text" name="question" matInput placeholder="Question">
    </mat-form-field>
  
  </form>
</mat-card-content>


<mat-card-actions>
    <button (click)="post(question)" mat-button>POST</button>
</mat-card-actions>


</mat-card>
```

question.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {ApiService} from './api.service'

@Component({

   selector:'question',
   templateUrl:'./question.component.html'

})

export class QuestionComponent{

    question = {}

    constructor(private api:ApiService){}

    post(question)
    {
        this.api.postQuestion(question);
    }
}
```

when i run my application.then i found these error:-

```
src/app/question.component.ts:7:16
    7    templateUrl:'./question.component.html'
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component QuestionComponent.


Error: src/app/question.component.html:9:36 - error TS2339: Property 'text' does not exist on type '{}'.

9       <input [(ngModel)]="question.text" name="question" matInput placeholder="Question">
                                     ~~~~

  src/app/question.component.ts:7:16
    7    templateUrl:'./question.component.html'
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component QuestionComponent.
```

How I resolve this issue?

Comment: `question = {}` you don't give it a type, so the compiler doesn't know it has a text property. Typescript isn't Javascript. Just initialize that property to an empty string or whatever it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

when you create an object `question = {}` Typescript infers the type as `{}` an object without properties. If you try to access any property, it will throw an error

**Solution**

Set the type of the object

```
question: { text?: string; } = {}
```

Or even better declare an interface

```
interface IQuestion {
  text?: string;
}

...
question: IQuestion = {}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to declare the type of the property named after 'question'. You can try following,

```
question:any = {};
```

It's a typescript strict type checking issue of recent update version. If you are using Angular then you can easily turn off this strict type checking by this way, [Turn off strict type checking in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70983942/4072927)

Answer (score 1):

You should change the type of `question` object to any

```
question: any = {};
```

Or

Create an interface :

```
    interface Question {
       text?: string;
       // other properties if you have ones
    }
```

And then set the type of question to Question

```
question: Question = {}
```

here is a working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b8hrcx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Property 'option' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)
If you are using Vue add

```js
"vueCompilerOptions": {
        "target": 2
    },
```

In your tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

It is because you do not have any keys name "text" in your object "question"
You can either add one key named "text" in the object or you can provide type definition to you object "question" .
something like below:

```
interface Iobject {
    text: string;
}

question: Iobject;
```

By doing this your error will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

This helps with **any**:

```
let a : any = {};
```