# TS7006: Parameter 'event' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, user-interface

In angular,

This is script

```
<button (click)="onClick($event)"> Greet </button>
     <button (click)="greeting='welcome' "> Greet </button> 
     {{greeting}}
```

This is event Logic

```
public greeting =""; 
 onClick(event) {
    console.log(event);
   this.greeting ='welcome';
  }
```

Comment: `onClick(event: any) { ... }` you need to explicitly type event arg

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Some alternatives you can use:

```
onClick(event: Event) {}

onClick(event: MouseEvent) {}
```

Also, if you are not using the parameter event for anything, you can remove it.

```
onClick() { ... }
```

Answer (score 6):

Reason: If you have any chance to use Angular in previous versions when you create a new project you might see some question like this. And this question is very important.
[image]

Fix:
You can either follow the stricter type checking rule or manually switch the stricter type checking to false. It worked for me.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

in tsconfig.js change

"noImplicitAny": false to true
or add it if it not found

Answer (score 1):

On click of that button on console, we can see `PoinerEvent { isTrusted": true }`

So in addition to `MouseEvent` or `Event` you can also use:

```
onClick(event: PointerEvent) {}
```

Check the docs at [PointerEvent MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent). "This interface inherits properties from MouseEvent and Event."